# How to change default color of GlBarGraphItem in PYQTgraph

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqtgraph

My goal is to create stacked 3d bar plot, for that, I am trying to change color of GlBarGraphItem from PYQTgraph library.

Here is my code:

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl
import numpy as np 

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
w = gl.GLViewWidget()
w.opts['distance'] = 100
w.showMaximized()
w.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: GLViewWidget')

ax = gl.GLAxisItem()
ax.setSize(20,20,20)
w.addItem(ax)

pos = np.mgrid[0:1,0:1,0:1].reshape(3,1,1).transpose(1,2,0)

size = np.empty((1,1,3)) 
size[...,0:2] = 1
size[...,2] = 5

bg = gl.GLBarGraphItem(pos, size)
##bg.setColor(1., 1., 1., 1.)
w.addItem(bg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

I tried to use .setColor() method with no success, the object (GlBarGraphItem) itself does not have a method for setting color I believe.

Any hint how to progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the [code](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/_modules/pyqtgraph/opengl/items/GLMeshItem.html#GLMeshItem) of the `GLMeshItem` `paint()` method is revised:

```
if self.colors is None:
    color = self.opts['color']
    if isinstance(color, QtGui.QColor):
        glColor4f(*fn.glColor(color))
    else:
        glColor4f(*color)
```

so the `setColor()` function expects a `QColor` or a tuple of 4 elements so you can use the following methods:

```
bg.setColor((0., 1., 0., 1))
```

[image]

```
color = QtGui.QColor("pink")
bg.setColor(color)
```

[image]

```
color = QtGui.QColor(120, 14, 12)
bg.setColor(color)
```

[image]